# I'm trying to find all the "#" characters in a string in C++ and replace them with "hash" but the regex does not recognise the character "#"

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to find all the "#" characters in a string in C++ and replace them with "hash" but the regex does not recognise the character `"#"` or `"\#"` or `"\\#"`. Any idea of what I have to put for it to find the #?

```
std::string local = std::regex_replace(test, "#", "hash");
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Use [std::string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) instead.

Comment: Must be using gcc. Regardless, as @RobertHarvey says, use `std::string::replace`. Regular expressions are overkill here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'd say that [boost::replace_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp163426992) is a better idea.

Comment: I know it might be overkill but it is not the only thing I have to replace (it's just the simplest one) so I was using regex for all the changes. I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Harvey suggested using std::sting::replace works well. It expects an index to replace though rather than a character. So you would have to use it in combination with something like `std::string::find like so:

```
int index;
while( (index = str.find("#') != std::string::npos) {
    str.replace(index, 1, "hash");
}
```

You could use the same idea for more complicated strings to match so if you don't need pattern replacement this will work.

Running example here: http://ideone.com/WqDZAl

Comment: Thanks, I was using the replace function but I already have to iterate throught a file to get the strings and I wanted to avoid to iterate again throught the string. I want to try what @Pete Becker suggested, the boost::replace_all, but does anybody know what library I have to add for it?

Comment: @Mulan that would be [boost](http://www.boost.org/). The specific bit of it you want is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo.html). You would include the `<boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>` to get the replace all function documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/replace_all.html).